# Spring Data Mongo version 1.9 is connected but can't make CRUD operations

Tags: java, spring, mongodb, spring-data-mongodb

I am using spring data mongodb 1.9 and I try to insert a document to my mongodb but it doesn't throws an error and the document is not inserted, my spring version is 4.3.8.RELEASE, my mongo java driver version is 3.2.0 and my mongodb server version is 3.0,

I try to configure the connection in several ways but any of them doesn't works, I try the following configurations:

```
@Configuration
public class MongoConfiguration extends AbstractMongoConfiguration {

    @Override
    public String getDatabaseName() {
        return "db";
    }

    @Override
    @Bean
    public Mongo mongo() throws Exception {
        List<MongoCredential> m = new ArrayList<MongoCredential>();
        m.add(MongoCredential.createCredential("user", "db", "password".toCharArray()));
        return new MongoClient(new ServerAddress("host", port), m);
    }

}
```

and also:

```
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" 
    xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
    xmlns:mongo="http://www.springframework.org/schema/data/mongo"
    xsi:schemaLocation="
          http://www.springframework.org/schema/data/mongo
          http://www.springframework.org/schema/data/mongo/spring-mongo-1.0.xsd
          http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
          http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd">

    <mongo:mongo id="mongo" host="host" port="port" />

    <bean id="mongoTemplate" class="org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.MongoTemplate" >
        <constructor-arg ref="mongo"/>
        <constructor-arg name="databaseName" value="db"/>
        <constructor-arg name="userCredentials" ref="userCredentials"/>
    </bean>

    <bean id="userCredentials" class="org.springframework.data.authentication.UserCredentials">
        <constructor-arg name="username" value="user" />
        <constructor-arg name="password" value="password" />
    </bean>

</beans>
```

Can someone help me to solve this issue?,

Thanks in advance.

Comment: suppose you have a look at these [examples](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-data-examples/tree/master/mongodb) on github and they may be helpful.

Comment: hi @RajithPemabandu I checked the link you mentioned but is all about spring boot and I am using spring core or maybe I didn't understand the examples

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved the problem by installing mongodb 3.2.13, mongo java driver 3.4.2 and spring data mongodb 1.10.3, maybe the versions that I was using have a version conflict, hope this help someone else.

Note: either of the two configurations works